# WP8 Page Transition Slow

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm working on an application which consists of multiple PivotElements in a PivotControl (about 5) each containing a LongListSelector which (when tapped) opens another page containing details on the selected item (items consist of 3 labels and an image).

The page transition to the detail page is already slow (meaning there is a moment of blackness between the SlideIn/SlideOut animations which is just a bit too long) but the transition back to the pivot page is even longer.

Is there any way I can improve performance in this scenario?

Comment: Without being able to see exactly what you're doing it's going to be hard to make anything but very general suggestions. Can you provide a repro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reduce the number of elements in your Visual Tree, evidently the layout pass is taking too long. My first step would be loading and unloading the LLS's on demand, when that pivot is selected.

Comment: Reducing the complexity in the Visual Tree works amazingly well - I can't believe I didn't think of that myself! Thank you! :)

Comment: Just optimized Telerik's templates and decreased elements count from 675 to 207 :) Thank you for the advise!